# Load jars from a subfolder of WEB-INF in Wildfly 8 server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly-8

I have a set of jars located inside  WEB-INF/jars/mylocation inside the war artifact. 
Are these jars available in the classpath automatically? If not , how should I make those available in classpath?

I am using WildFly 8 as the application server. And the deployed application is of type .ear.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly), or better download [java ee 7 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/java_ee-7-fr-eval-spec/)
and read EE.8.3   (EE.8.3.1 for web containres)